# How to link file or image from wordpress plugin dir to theme by using themes function.php, is it possible?

Tags: plugins, themes, urls, bug

I have some image file in my plugin directory. I want to display those file by using my theme function. I am trying many way but something was wrong. Theme and plugin both dir is loaded at same time.

Can you help me?

```
    $link = plugins_url( 'img/btn-arrow-left.png',__FILE__ );
    //$link = plugin_dir_url( 'img/btn-arrow-left.png',__FILE__ );
    $aro_left = '<img src="'.$link.'img/btn-arrow-left.png"/>';
    var_dump($link);

Output :

string 'http://localhost/project/wp-content/plugins/C:/wamp/www/project/wp-content/themes/Buddhist/img/btn-arrow-left.png' (length=113)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Try `plugins_url('plugin_dir_name/img/name of.png').`

Comment: I'll get no points but he was helped I assure you all!